# Controls doesn't show if heavy process

Tags: c#, winforms, busy-waiting

I use c# in winform.

Before a very heavy function, I want to show a waiting form to prevent the user. The form opens, but the controls in it are not drawn.

In the following code, waitingForm is a little form, with only a textbox and a progressbar

```
using (WaitingForm waitingForm = new WaintingForm())
{
  waitingForm.Show();
  HeavyFunction();
}
```

I see only two white rectangles, where the controls should appear. Why this happens ?

Comment: you need to do your heavy function outside the UI thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't show the waiting form before the heavy processing and expect the UI to remain responsive. The thread that you're clogging up with `HeavyFunction()` is the same one that is responsible for drawing forms, controls and maintaining the UI. Use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or the [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to offload the heavy processing to another thread.

EDIT: Also, please consider Ron Beyer's input regarding [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: I agree with this except the recommendation for `BackgroundWorker` or `ThreadPool`. This is a good example of where to use async/await or Tasks. BackgroundWorker is effectively depreciated as well as working with low level threads except in specific circumstances.

Comment: @Ron Beyer Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. Edited to include link to async/await article on MSDN.

Comment: I hope there was a simple solution like form.WaitForControlDrawn(). I look for the async/await solution, but it's a feature of Net 4.5. And I forgot to say that I need to target XP SP3, so I'm limited to Net 4.0. I already use backgroundworker, but it's a hugh work for a simple thing. I'm looking for ThreadPool instead.

Comment: I find that a NuGet package install the async/await functionnality for .Net4.0. I'm looking for those functions.